# problema de acentuação no banco

Tags: php, mysql

Amigos, estou com problema para gravar com acentuação no banco assim que alterei a versão para o PHP 5.6

Sei que tem várias perguntas sobre esse assunto, mas já testei várias delas e não funciona de jeito nenhum, recreie todo o banco de dado, tabelas, tudo do zero e não funciona.

Estou usando UTF8.
Alguma recomendação para resolver o problema?

Att

Comment: Você está usando PDO ?

Comment: huahuaua, se vc conseguir me diga como foi pois até hj não consegui migrar para a versão 7 por causa disso e acho que deveria começar do zero, banco, tabela etc...

Answer (score 1):

Você deve configurar a codificação no PHP, basta inserir essa linha:

```
ini_set('default_charset', 'utf-8');
```

Também, na hora que você efetua a conexão com o banco de dados, exemplo utilizando o PDO:

```
$pdocon->exec("set names utf8");
```

Para MSQLI:

```
$con = mysqli_connect($DB_SERVER, $DB_USER_READER, $DB_PASS_READER, $DB_NAME, $DB_PORT);

mysqli_set_charset($con, 'utf8');
```

Answer (score 0):

Já tentei ini_set('default_charset', 'utf-8'); e nada.

Também tentei da seguinte forma e não funcionou.

mysqli_query($conexao, "SET NAMES 'utf8'");
mysqli_query($conexao, 'SET character_set_connection=utf8');
mysqli_query($conexao, 'SET character_set_client=utf8');
mysqli_query($conexao, 'SET character_set_results=utf8');

O problema é só quando grava no BD, pra exibir no navegador a acentuação carrega normal.

Quando utilizava a versão 5.4 não tinha esse problema, só foi migrar que o pesadelo começou.

Comment: Eu editei minha resposta, tente daquele modo. Depois exclua essa resposta aqui que estou comentando.